# elementary logarithm equation $4e^{i\pi}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Why does $4e^{i\pi}=-4$?

It means that $e^{i\pi}=-1$ why is that?

Comment: $e^{ix}$ is **defined** as $\cos x + i\sin x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. See for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155068

Comment: Technically, you can define $e^z$ in general, and prove it. For example, if you define $e^z$ in terms of the power series, or $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+z/n\right)^n$. @mrf

Comment: I'm well aware that there are many different ways to define $e^z$, but going via Euler's formulas seem to be the most common one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice,

Using Euler's formula $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta$ as follows
$$4e^{i\pi}=4(\cos \pi+i\sin \pi)=4(-1+i(0))=-4$$